# Regsvr32.exe - DllRegisterServer entry point was not found

Tags: registry, regsvr32, dllregistration

I am trying to register MDMLib.dll using regsvr32.exe but I am getting given error

```
DllRegisterServer entry point was not found.
```

I am trying to register dll in given way :

```
1. First way
    1. Open cmd with admin rights.
    2. C:\Windows\system32: regsvr32.exe MDMLib.dll
    3. Press enter and got error.
 2. Second way
    1. Open cmd with admin rights.
    2. C:\Windows\syswow64: regsvr32.exe MDMLib.dll
    3. Press enter and got error.
 3. Third way
    1. Open cmd prompt in Safe mode.
    3. C:\Windows\system32: regsvr32.exe MDMLib.dll
    4. Press enter and got error.
```

Still getting the same error. can anybody please suggest me solutions for this?